# Lemon vs lime in choc chip cookie recipe

Tags: baking, substitutions

Can I use lime instead of lemon in my choc chip cookie recipe? It calls for 1/2 teaspoon and I have no lemons. Would it be better to just omit or use 1/2 teaspoon of lime juice?

Comment: Well, welcome to the community. It would be helpful to provide as much information as possible (recipes for example). The people here are fairly active, but lie Jefromi said, you shouldn't expect a instant response. If you need an quicker response, you could try the chat room (requires 20 rep, but that isn't hard to get if you hang around here a bit). http://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat

Answer (score 5):

It's really hard to say without seeing your recipe. (Why is there lemon juice in the first place?) In general, lime juice will provide about the same amount of acidity (good), and the flavor will be similar but not quite the same (probably okay, maybe won't go as well with the chocolate). If you've made this before and you can't really taste the lemon juice flavor in the final product, then don't worry about it. If you haven't, well, I doubt half a teaspoon in a whole batch of cookies is providing substantial flavor, so I'd say go for it, unless the cookies are for something *really* important.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...have never used this site before and was feeling really desperate with batter melting by the second. Went without and the cookies were as awesome as ever!